# Create Video Programmatically with Qt 5.0

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ffmpeg

We have a QT application that renders programmatically generated QPixmaps one by one to the display and we would like to save this output to a video file.

I know that in the past people have recommended using ffmpeg or opencv with Qt to do this.  In Qt 5, however, the new QtMultimedia module seems to expose some of this type of functionality.

It is now possible, for example, to save video from a camera source in Qt 5 by using the QMediaRecorder as described in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecorder.html#details.

With this new functionality, is there any way to use Qt 5 to save our programmatically generated video, or am I still better off using a third party library?

Answer (score 6):

This is actually possible as early as Qt 4.7 through the use of QVideoFrame and QAbstractVideoSurface. Qt even has this excellent example for creating a Video Widget that can display programmatically constructed QVideoFrames:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/multimedia-videowidget.html

You can combine this widget with the mapping capabilities of QVideoFrame to fill individual video frames with properly formatted data. That should look like something like this:

Instantiate your videoWidget:

```
VideoWidgetSurface * videoWidget = new VideoWidgetSurface();
QSize videoSize(500,500); // supplement with your video dimensions

// look at VideoWidgetSurface::supportedPixelFormats for supported formats
QVideoSurfaceFormat format( videoSize, QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32, QAbstractVideoBuffer::QPixmapHandle)

// possibly fill with initial frame?

videoWidget->start(format);
```

... and when you want to update the current frame of the video widget:

```
// If you don't need the data in any past frames you can probably just create one frame
// and just use it repeadtly (as VideoWidgetSurface only keeps track of one frame at a time)
QVideoFrame aFrame(32 * format.frameWidth()  * format.frameHeight(),format.frameSize(), 32 * format.frameWidth(),format.pixelFormat());

aFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::WriteOnly);

QRgb * pixels = aFrame.bits();

// perform pixel manipulation here...

aFrame.unmap();

videoWidget->present(aFrame);
```

.. and to end playback...

```
videoWidget.stop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I see that this is how one would display a programmatically generated frame in a Video Widget, but my issue is different.  I would like to save the video out to a file (.avi, .mp4, etc).  Do you know if this is possible?  It looks to me like Qt5 uses a QMediaRecorder to save video to file, but I don't see how to get a QVideoFrame into the QMediaRecorder.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yeah, that is a much more difficult problem in Qt. Looking through the Qt 5.0 documentation I couldn't really find any direct support for that. I think your best bet is to use the facilities of QVideoFrame to keep track of essential frame information then use a third party library to write to file. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: I've been using [qtffmpegwrapper](https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/QtFFMpegWrapper).  Its less straightforward that a built in Qt class and doesn't handle audio, but it does the job.

Comment: @Joey Thanks very much, you should submit your comment as answer as it actually answer's OP's question.

Comment: @Matt I posted the original question, and my motivation was to find a way to save video without a third party class like qtffmpegwrapper.  That's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @Joey Oh heh heh I see.  Thanks for the tip on that anyway, I am grappling with this exact issue right now, I'm surprised that with all the functionality Qt has, saving video isn't it!

Comment: @Joey: It's okay to answer your own questions. Please go ahead and do so.

Comment: @GManNickG: I didn't post the qtffmpegwrapper as an answer because it is not a solution for creating video using QT alone.  It requires the third party ffmpeg library to work.  I was looking for a way to create video using Qt exclusively.

Comment: Example linked seems moved to: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-multimedia-videowidget-example.html

Answer (score 2):

[... Three years later]. As clarified above, the question is about generating video FILES (e.g. .avi, .mpeg, animated .gif, and/or .mp4).

It looks like **FFmpeg** is really NOT an option for **commercial applications** -- See for example: https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html (the "Note that FFmpeg ..." sentence and the last two paragraphs on the page).

It really looks like Qt still has no native capability to generate video FILES (e.g. .avi, .mpeg, animated .gif, and/or .mp4) -- *See update below.*

AM I right about this? (with Qt 5.5.1 being the latest available Qt release at this time).

OR ARE THERE any licensable (for a fee) packages which can be used with a Qt/C++ Windows application which can create video FILES? (from a sequence of programmatically generated QPixmaps or QImages -- or at least with the possibility of receiving frame image data from those Qt classes?).

(We currently don't need any audio in video files generated from our Qt application).

UPDATE: Unfortunately, Qt commercial license support folks are confirming that, currently (as of Qt 5.6), there is no way to get a sequence of programmatically generated QImages (e.g. renders from an application QWidget) into the QMediaRecorder class -- or any other way of generating synthetic animations and saving them as video files. ("There is no API for that").

Comment: The licensing page is clear: FFmpeg is licensed under LGPL, with some GPL parts. If you compile FFmpeg without `--enable-gpl` and without `--enable-nonfree`, then you end up with a fully LGPL library that you can use in any commercial project.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as long as you aren't charging for the capability that you'd use FFmpeg for, and you use a separate executable for FFmpeg, you are following the LGPL and GPL licenses.  Whether or not you'd like to risk being the target of litigation is a different topic.

I have the same need (commerically) and cannot offer you a solution other than using FFmpeg as a callable executable, which is allowed under these licenses.

Edit:  This thread may be useful for you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205689/using-exe-of-program-with-gnu-general-public-license-version-2-0-for-commercial